# Office Fabric UI React - Selection Problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-fabric

I'm using Office UI Fabric React components and i'm trying to make the selection work.

What i want is to get information on which row of DetailsList is selected.

This is what i've tried so far (keep in mind that i'm using javascript, not typescript).

```
        this._rowSelectIrf = new Selection({
            onSelectionChanged: () => this.setState({ selectionDetails: this._getSelectionDetails() })
        })

    _getSelectionDetails = () => {
        const selectionCount = this._rowSelectIrf.getSelectedCount();

        console.log(selectionCount + " counted")

        return `${selectionCount} items selected`;

    }

                <MarqueeSelection selection={this._rowSelectIrf}>
                    <DetailsList
                        onColumnHeaderClick={this.onColumnClick}
                        items={this.state.sortedItems}
                        setKey="items"
                        columns={this.state.columns}
                        layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.fixedColumns}
                        selection={this._rowSelectIrf}
                        selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}
                        ariaLabelForSelectionColumn="Toggle selection"
                        ariaLabelForSelectAllCheckbox="Toggle selection for all items"
                        onItemInvoked={this.onItemInvoked}
                        selectionMode="single"
                    />
                </MarqueeSelection>`
```

Selectin any row does literally nothing. I might've messed something up when converting from TS to JS so any tip is highly appreciated.  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Almost a year has passed and i'm getting downvoted after having to answer my own quesiton. Gotta love stack overflow lately. Either way, its so old i dont even remember what it was about and i was too much of a beginner to give a proper answer.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote for that. At least there is a conclusion now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by moving the selection to state. Not sure if this is the best approach, but i wont complain as long as it works.

```
selectCon: new Selection({
onSelectionChanged: () => this.setState({ selectionDetails: this._getSelectionDetails() })
}),
```

Comment: Main reason this works is because you are triggering a re-render here by setting the state again. Probably could have set any variable in state and it would have had the same effect.